# Performing browser action on two different pages

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

I have below files with me

**manifest.json**

```
{
        "name": "Get Response URL",
        "version": "1.0",
        "manifest_version": 2,
        "name": "Test" ,
        "browser_action": {
        "icon":"icon.png"
        },
        "background": {
        "persistent": false,
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
         },
        "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png"
      },
        "permissions":["https://myblog.com/*"] ,//Put All your URL here
        "manifest_version": 2
 }
```

**background.js**

```js
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) { //Fired when User Clicks ICON

    if (tab.url.indexOf("https://myblog.com/page1.html")==0) { // Inspect whether the place where user clicked matches with our list of URL
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
            "file": "page2.js"
        }, function () { // Execute your code
            console.log("Script Executed .. "); // Notification on Completion
        });

    }
    else  if (tab.url.indexOf("https://myblog.com/page2.html")==0) { // Inspect whether the place where user clicked matches with our list of URL
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
            "file": "page1.js"
        }, function () { // Execute your code
            console.log("Script Executed .. "); // Notification on Completion
        });
    }
});
```

**Page1.html**

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Page1</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type='button' name='submit' id='myBtn' value='click here to move to next page' onclick="document.location.href='page2.html';" />
</body>
</html>
```

**page2.html**

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Page2</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" name="textBox" id="myText" />
</body>
</html>
```

And to two JavaScript files **page1.js** and **page2**.

**page1.js**

```js
var button=document.getElementById("myBtn");
button.click();
```

**Page2.js**

```js
document.getElementById("myText").value="Text Box";
```

I have developed a Chrome extension. On first page when I click the Chrome extension icon the functionality is working good as per JavaScript file(**page1.js**) for https://myblog.com/page1 page.

And what I am doing on https://myblog.com/page1 page with the help of page1.js is to just click a button to move to second page that is https://myblog.com/page2. Now I want that page2.js should wrok  on page https://myblog.com/page2 as scripted(page2.js) but its not working.

Script is working good when I click the extension icon on page1 and then again click the extension icon on page2.

But I want to extension icon should be clicked on page1 not repetitively.

**Edited the Question**

- **Added page1.html and page2.html**
- **page1.js and page2.js**

Is it possible to doing the same.
If yes where I am doing the mistake?

Comment: So `page1.js` clicks the button to go to page2.html?  The way you have it coded, your extension requires you to click on the browser action while on page 2 in order to execute `page2.js`.  If that's not what you want, you may need your background script to listen for the navigation (and whether you've already clicked the icon while on page1).  As an aside, you should probably use a page action instead of a browser action.

Comment: Do you _need_ to click anything on page 1, or do you just need to navigate to page 2?

Comment: @Teepeemm exactly the way you are thinking I want to do the same Since the extension requires multiple page navigation .Is using the Page Action correct way to implement the same ? If you have any idea then will realy appriciate it.

Comment: @Xan yes I have a button on page1 ( I have edited the Question) when the extension icon will be clicked the browser will navigated to page2 which have a text box and with the help of page2.js I want to enter some text into that.

Answer (score 1):

here's what you need to do.
Your code block `chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {` makes the JS functions to execute only when you click the icon. That's why your Page 1 works whereas the Page 2 doesn't.

You want the **page2.js** to run as soon as the Page2.html is opened right? Hence change the coding of your Page2.html. Add the below code in the **page2.html** itself.

`document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
//Do work
});`

What this will do is, as soon as the Page2.html is loaded, it will execute the Javascript. Eventhough it works in most of the browsers, but for IE 8 and below it won't.

If you need for IE 8 and below too, then try using the following code:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
function funtionToBeCalled(){
// code that will be exected after dom ready
}

window.onload=funtionToBeCalled;
</script>
```